# About the .gitignore question, .cxx folder in the Android project

Tags: android, git, gitignore

Here's a question about Git, .gitignore on Android!

======================================================

**Q1) What files are created in myproject/app/.cxx?**

I am using ndk, jni in android project.
It seems that the files related to this are being automatically changed in myproject/app/.cxx.

When I try to branch move, the files in this folder are changed, so I have a problem that I have to commit.

So I want to add that directory to .gitignore,
I don't know exactly what that directory is, so I'm wondering if I can add it to .gitignore

======================================================

**Q2) I have multiple .gitignore files.**

If I add that directory (myproject/app/.cxx) to .gitignore,

There is also a .gitignore file in the "myproject" folder,

There is also a .gitignore file in the "myproject/app" folder.

Should i edit .gitignore in "myproject/app"??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to answer your second question, You need to have only one .gitignore file at the root of the project folder.

As to answer your first question, all the .cxx files must be ignored. You can have the below line in .gitignore file.

** **/.cxx**

If you have already tracked this file, use the below commands after adding the above line in .gitignore file

git rm --cached . (Don't forget the dot at the end)

git add .

git commit -m "Commit-message"

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I have already solved this.
I just left two gitignore files,
I added the .cxx to the gitignore file at the root of the project, so it seems to work as desired.

Comment: Please accept the answer, so that, it could help others find a solution for the same query